# flexbox: resizing elements

Tags: css, resize, flexbox

So here's a hopefully easy newbie flexbox challenge:

I have a flexbox with two children (Left & Right). I want Left to be 500px wide and Right to fill the rest of the space UNLESS Right would be < 400px wide, in which case I want Left to obediently start shrinking. Any good solutions? It seems like this should be pretty easy, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around which elements to combine...

Thank-you!

PS: Oh, BTW: Left contains an image to crop (rather than resize), so this seems like a really common issue: image on left, text on right: want them to look good at all screen widths...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea of how you could get that to work using `flex-basis` and media queries:

```css
html {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.left {
  flex-basis: 500px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: #f00;
}

.right {
  background-color: #00f;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 0%;
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .left {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

image on the left is 500px wide;  text on the right is set to min-width: 400px. Fiddle here --> http://jsfiddle.net/LrscjLoq/

```
    <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-image">
    </div>
    <div class="flex-box" style="min-width:400px">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.
    </div>
</div>

.flex-container {
list-style: none;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-flow: row;
justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex-image {
margin: 5px;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 1.5em;
text-align: center;
flex-basis: 500px;
background-image: url(noimage.png);
}

.flex-box {
margin: 5px;
color: gray;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 1.5em;
text-align: center;
-ms-flex: 1;
flex: 1;
```

}